# Will front-end built in angular js and three js work with magento?

Tags: configurable-product, magento2, javascript, js-css

We are currently building a web app e-commerce store using mainly Angular JS and Three JS. We are only offering one product in six different sizes. The user can then customize the product with colors, texts, etc.

An example of the project we’re building would be similar to a web app that allows the user to customize and purchase a t-shirt in different sizes. I don't know if it matters, but the store will serve one single market to begin with (Sweden).

We're almost done with the front-end and my question is what type of platform and why, should we use for the back-end? We just want to use something very simple to get the store running, but with options for development further down the road.

Our initial plan was to use Magento as our back-end platform together with hosting as it offers many possibilities for new products or features, however, we don't want to be limiting ourselves.

For example, we have created our check-out process for the front-end, but it seems that Magento has its own check-out process that can only be visually modified? (I know very little about Magento so far).

So, the most critical questions that I am looking to learn about:

What platform to use, and why?
What do I need in addition to the back-end in order for the store to function? Hosting? From what I have understood, payment processing etc. is something that you install through Magento?
Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated as I am eager to learn all about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Magento2 provide set of [rest api](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/rest/bk-rest.html). You can use custom js framework to build frontend app. For example current checkout it is frontend app build in knockoutjs .

But I don't see any benefits to reimplement Magento in custom js framework.